# Prevent PrettyPhoto from closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

the script i created uses PrettyPhoto to load an ifram on which there is an upload page going on, the upload works great the image is uploaded and the url is returned back to the page for preview, but not saved into the database just yet...
so far so good, i just want to add a function that if a picture is not saved and the user hits close button it will promt to either save or dismiss which it will make an ajax call to either remove the uploaded picture or save its url into the database

does anyone have an idea how to do that? not the ajax part i have everything under control, just need to know how to prevent the prettyphoto close button from closing directly

ps: i tried the callback function but what it does it that it closes then executes, but i need the execution to be done before closing

any help would be much appreciated

thank you

Comment: as a work around i duplicated the themes (since i'm using two instances of PrettyPhoto) and edited the one that loads the iframe in the stylesheet adding display:block; for the .pp_close class so the button doesn't show up and i replaced it with a custom button from within the iframe to perform the checks and close the popup with window.parent.$.prettyPhoto.close(); which im sure you all know, that was a quick solution since i need this a bit urgent, however any answer to the first question is always welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can tweak the prettyPhoto js code but that will effect all your popups, so as you found the workaround of the close function inside the iframe then that's it, you didn't have to duplicate themes and hide the close button on the its stylesheet, you could have simply let jquery do so from withing the iframe, just include this code into your iframe

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     window.parent.$('.pp_close').css('display', 'none');
});
</script>
```